# Toolbar gets pushed back in landscape

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

Within my **layout-sw600dp-land** folder this layout file is for the main activity the app starts with. Once the app has started, two fragments are programmatically added to the relevant frame layouts.

This current layout causes the toolbar to be pushed back behind both frame layouts.

[image: activity with two fragments with pushed back toolbar]

The viewpager fragment and the fragment on the right take up the toolbars space and the toolbar gets pushed back behind them both.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="?attr/ToolBarStyle" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingRight="4dp" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingRight="4dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/nav_drawer_layout" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What is the appropriate syntax for a dualpane(fragments) toolbar layout?

Comment: DrawerLayout works with 2 views. In your case you have 3 (at least) views.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti how would you propose how to create the type of layout I want to create?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Adding a margin to the top of both frame layouts allows the toolbar to become visible, is there a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: MOve the toolbar inside the first LL.

Comment: This happens when I move the toolbar inside the first LL and before the DL [Screenshot](http://ctrlv.in/469833)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:theme="?attr/ToolBarStyle" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/nav_drawer_layout" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

An important thing to note is that I wanted to have the navigation drawer to be presented above all content, even the toolbar, that's why @GabrieleMariotti's comment did not lead to my ideal solution. With this layout, both fragments can be displayed as well as having the drawer layout to display over the action bar.